# SQL Server - Autoincrementing on a generated table

Tags: sql-server

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_new_table_id PRIMARY KEY(id);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT new_table ON
```

Basically, I want to create a new table based on the structure of an existing one, then turn on autoincrementing for the ID field. However, when I try to insert rows I get this:

```
Table 'new_table ' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong or how I should actually be going about this?

Comment: Have you defined the `ID` field of the `new_table` as `IDENTITY`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table you create doesn't have an identity column. If you inspect the code you posted, you will notice that nowhere is an identity declared. I think you are confusing the concept of `PRIMARY KEY` and `IDENTITY`. They are distinct and unrelated. You cannot create a table with identity column using SELECT ... INTO ...

Comment: If it cannot be created with `SELECT ... INTO` then is there another way to create a table based on the columns of another table?

Comment: You can (and should!) always use `CREATE TABLE ...` and have tight and precise control of the schema. IDENTITY is just *one* of the many problems you'll encounter. For the record, there *is* a roundabout way: `SELECT field1, field2, ... INTO ... FROM ... WHERE 0=1` will create a table with no rows and no `ID` column. Then add the `ID` column as identity, and then use `INSERT ... SELECT` to transfer the data.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - You can do `SELECT IDENTITY ( INT, 1,1) AS id, foo, bar INTO new_table FROM old_table WHERE 1=2;
`

Answer (score 2):

the column needs to be specified with " identity(1,1)" option.  First 1 is the starting point and second is the increment.

Answer (score 2):

set identity_insert  on  does not actually do what you think it does.  It disables autoincrement (temporarily) so that you can hard code values in there.

Here's more info on that... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create the new table without the use of "select ... into" and specify the column as an identity column.

Use the "set identity_insert .. on" before you copy the data over.  Then, "set identity_insert ... off" when you're done.

If you want to cheat on the first part, you can use the management studio. Right click original table... goto the designer.  Add identity option for the desired column.  Then save off the script but do not commit.  Might want to manipulate the newly generate script to create the new table.  There are other more sophisticated solutions if you're going to have to do this repeatedly.  But this by far is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Here could be the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_new_table_id PRIMARY KEY(id, idColumn);
```

Specify the id column.